# Chinese seal on a spanish manuscript (Characters identified: 謨區查印)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I doing a research thesis of a XVI Spanish manuscript. But I find a Chinese seal at the beginning and at the end of the binding book.

Could someone help me translate the seal or identify it origin or provenance?

[image]

Comment: The seal says "Seal of Boxer" (someone's name). This probably refers to [Charles Ralph Boxer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._R._Boxer), and the manuscript you're looking at is the [Boxer Codex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxer_Codex).

Comment: @dROOOze, mr boxer, his chinese name is “博沙爾” in hong kong https://www4.hku.hk/hongrads/graduates/k-s-g-hon-d-litt-hon-d-phil-f-b-a-charles-ralph-boxer  , or “博克塞” in macau https://www.macaumemory.mo/entries_86779eeb0ab644c2b9b7cdf807209760#:~:text=歷史學家%E3%80%82,斯特（Sandhurst）軍校%E3%80%82

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 I think "謨區查" is Japanese - these characters would be transcribed as [ぼ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%AC%A8#Readings)[く](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8D%80#Readings)[さ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9F%A5#Readings) (*bo-ku-sa*) in [kan'on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kan-on).

Comment: Yes. I studying the Boxer Codex; the red seal appear at the bigining and the end of the binding manuscript.
So, the seal belongs to Charles Ralph Boxer and is a japanese seal (not chinese).
Thank you. So much.